# Is FileHandle.write thread safe?

Tags: ios, multithreading

I'm trying to debug an elusive crash in my app.  After running uneventfully for many minutes, the app will halt with `Message from debugger: terminated due to memory issue`.  There is no stack trace.

I've determined the crash is linked to a section of code that copies bytes into a `UInt8` array.  That same array may be written to the file system immediately before or after.  I know from sad experience that you can't read and write data to and from the same array from different threads.  It leads to a crash very much like the one I'm experiencing.  But I've been very careful in my implementation.  The code that writes bytes to the array and the code that reads bytes from it all run on the same serial `DispatchQueue`.

But maybe there's another thread?  Does a write really complete before `FileHandle.write` returns, or is there some background processing?

```
func bug() {
    let bufferSize = ...
    var fileHandle:FileHandle = ...
    var fileIndex:UInt64 = ...

    var bytes = [UInt8](repeating:0, count:bufferSize)

    fileHandle.seek(toFileOffset: fileIndex)
    fileHandle.write(Data(bytes))
    for pos in 0..<bufferSize {
        bytes[pos] = ...        // Can my app crash here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FileHandle.write shouldn't create another thread. I think the most likely explanation of the "Message from debugger: terminated due to memory issue" error is that your app is running out of memory due to some reason. Probably something is not deallocating correctly.

Are you allocating multiple UInt8 byte arrays in a loop?

Comment: The UInt8 array is allocated once at the beginning of execution, and recycled.  I tried creating a copy of the array for writing, but that didn't fix the problem, so it's unlikely it's a threading issue.  I've run my program under the Allocations and the Leaks Instruments within Xode.  I can't get it to crash under Instruments, but there's no indication of runaway memory growth.